# Form Input will redirect to text entry

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

Is it possible to create an input box in HTML that when the user enters a word it will redirect to the HTML file? For example, they input "Doctor" then it will redirect to page doctor.html?

Need some help with this, it's for a school project. Thanks :)

Comment: Please search javascript, `document.location.href` on google to find a method.

Comment: Yes it is. What have you tried to solve this problem?

Comment: @Barmar My school doesn't teach programming. For the project, I am building a website on my own, I just thought this would be a good feature to include in the site I'm building. I have been trying to do research into it but couldn't find much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```js
let button = document.getElementById('go');
button.addEventListener('click',function(){
  let word = document.getElementById('word');
      console.log( word.value +'.html' );
      //window.location.href = word.value +'.html';
      // uncomment above to go to /doctor.html
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="word" value="doctor">
<button id="go">go</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to do something very similar to this code but it wasn't working.